# storybook addon readme wrong display order

Tags: reactjs, readme, storybook

My issue here is that I am trying to display my story with the readme addon but it doesn't display in the order I want it to and I don't see how my actual code is different in any way than the one from the github exemple.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { storiesOf, configure } from '@storybook/react'
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions'
import { withDocs } from 'storybook-readme'

import ActionButton from 'action-button'

import actionButtonReadme from './documentation/ActionButton.md'

storiesOf('Components', module)
    .add('ActionButton', withDocs(actionButtonReadme, () => {
        return <ActionButton btnClass='btn btn-trans btn-info mgt-10 mgr-5'
            iconClass='fa fa-info'
            tooltipText='Info button'
            clickAction={action('transparent info button')}
        />
    }))
```

**ActionButton.md**

````
# ActionButton

### Usage
```javascript
import ActionButton from 'action-button'
```

### Exemple
````

**addon.js**

```
import '@storybook/addon-actions/register'
import '@storybook/addon-options/register'
import 'storybook-readme/register'
```

**config.js**

```
import {
    configure
} from '@storybook/react'
import { setOptions } from '@storybook/addon-options'

function loadStories() {
    require('./index.js')
}

configure(loadStories, module)

setOptions({
    name: 'b2-common-components'
})
```

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a04d.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALm2I.png)

**Demo from github**

```
import { withDocs } from 'storybook-readme';
import ButtonREADME from '../components/components/button/README.md';

storiesOf('Button', module)
// add only one README (also supports multiple as array)
    .add('Default', withDocs(ButtonREADME, () => {
        return <Button onClick={action('clicked')} label="Hello Button"/>;
}));
```

I am wondering where did I get wrong in my code.

Answer (score -1):

I finally give up and use the `widthDocs` that I was avoiding for this reason https://github.com/tuchk4/storybook-readme/issues/43.

Using the `widthDocs` method and the `<!-- SCRIPT -->` tag inside the `.md` file help me solve this with some issues concerning the style and with the possibility of adding the story and my custom component at only one part of the `.md` file.